# how can i insert data i got from api into mysql using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, api

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    var aid = JSON.stringify(response.articles[1].author);
    //if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!!!!!");
    console.log(aid);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO db1 (id,fname) VALUES (5,aid)";
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```

> **HERE IS MY CODE  THAT IS NOT WORKING I AM USING BODY-PARSE AND EXPRESS TOO!!!** but the error mentioned that in MySQL syntax how can i solve it  ?

Comment: Please share your detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sequelize ORM for MySQL.

[Sequelize Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)

Example Create Usage with ExpressJS

```
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

router.get('/create_user', (req,res) => {
 user.create({
  username,
  password
 }).then((usr) => {
   res.send(usr)
 })
})
```